# Determine whether the given binary relation is equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$D$ is the binary relation defined on $R$ as follows: For all $x,y\in R,xDy\Leftrightarrow xy >0$.

Determine whether the given binary relation is equivalence relation and if it is, give the reason why, and if it is not, give the reason why as well.

I'm confused whether it's equivalence or not, considering that if you count $0$, then it won't be equivalence because $0\times0$ isn't $> 0$, but if $0$ isn't counted, then it is equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a binary relation is a equivalence relation or not depends on the underlying set. As you said, if $D$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ it can not be a equivalence relation since $\langle 0, 0\rangle \not \in D$. If you change your underlying set to be $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ you get a different relation.